# downloading satellite map for a specific region - R

Tags: r, import, spatial, ggmap, r-sp

I have run sum analysis on points summarized within a SpatialPointsDataFrame:

```
> trjct_pts
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 104559 
extent      : 696621.4, 696688.7, 167659.2, 167739.8  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       : Intensity_kJ 
min values  :      161.951 
max values  :     1192.526
```

Which I have used to create 2 rasters:

```
library(raster)
  rockfall_count <- raster (xmn = 696583.6, xmx = 696799.6, ymn = 167579.6, ymx = 167789.6, res = 2,
                              crs = "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")
  rockfall_intensity <- raster (xmn = 696583.6, xmx = 696799.6, ymn = 167579.6, ymx = 167789.6, res = 2,
                                  crs = "+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs")

  # count unique ID per raster 
  rockfall_count <- rasterize(trjct_points_coords, rockfall_count, fun = "count", by = ID)
  rockfall_count 
  plot(rockfall_count,col=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))


  # average kinetic energy per raster cell
  rockfall_intensity <- rasterize(trjct[, c('x', 'y')], rockfall_intensity, trjct$Etot, fun = mean)
  plot(rockfall_intensity, col=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))
```

For nice illustration, I would like to download the corresponding satellite image. I have tried the following:

```
library(rgdal)
longlatcoor<-spTransform(trjct_pts,CRS("+proj=longlat"))
coordinates(longlatcoor)
longlatcoor 

library(ggmap)
library(ggplot2)

# Set a range
lat <- c(-13.4003, -13.39943)                
lon <- c(35.419, 35.41961)   

# Get a map
map <- get_map(location = c(lon = mean(lon), lat = mean(lat)), zoom = 14,
               maptype = "satellite", source = "google")
ggmap(map)

#limit lon and lat.      
tschamut <- ggmap(map)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-13.4003, -13.39943), expand = c(0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(35.419, 35.41961), expand = c(0, 0))
tschamut
```

However, R crashes everytime i try to run this code, so i suspect something is seriously wrong with it. I derived the number used in the code from the bounding box:

```
> longlatcoor
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 104559 
extent      : -13.4003, -13.39943, 35.419, 35.41961  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 
variables   : 1
names       : Intensity_kJ 
min values  :      161.951 
max values  :     1192.526
```

How can I import the aerial photograph into R ?

Comment: On what line does R crash? Do you get an error message of any kind? How much RAM do you have available? It might be best to edit your original post to include this info.

Comment: it crashes on the tschamut line, i also figure why: `cannot allocate memory block of size 16777216 Tb`.  I am not sure why this happens. The spatial data points are derived from a raster file from ArcGIS with this specification: `Layer Spatial Reference System
+proj=somerc +lat_0=46.95240555555556 +lon_0=7.439583333333333 +k_0=1 +x_0=2600000 +y_0=1200000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=674.374,15.056,405.346,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs

Layer Extent (layer original source projection)
696583.0723235532641411,167577.0599993921932764 : 696807.9223235532408580,167791.5599993921932764`